# DataTables warning: table id=dupePairs - Ajax error

Tags: wordpress, contacts, duplicate-contacts, ajax, nginx

Getting this error when running any merge rule in Civi 5.10.4.

[image]

I tracked it down to a 502 ajax request failure triggered by this post:

admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fajax%2Fdedupefind&reset=1&rgid=19&gid=258&limit=&criteria=%7B%7D&snippet=4&draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=is_selected_input&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=dst_image&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B2%5D%5Bdata%5D=dst&columns%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B3%5D%5Bdata%5D=src_image&columns%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B4%5D%5Bdata%5D=src&columns%5B4%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B5%5D%5Bdata%5D=dst_email&columns%5B5%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B5%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B6%5D%5Bdata%5D=src_email&columns%5B6%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B6%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B7%5D%5Bdata%5D=dst_street&columns%5B7%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B7%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B8%5D%5Bdata%5D=src_street&columns%5B8%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B8%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B9%5D%5Bdata%5D=dst_postcode&columns%5B9%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B9%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B9%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B9%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B9%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B10%5D%5Bdata%5D=src_postcode&columns%5B10%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B10%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B10%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B10%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B10%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B11%5D%5Bdata%5D=conflicts&columns%5B11%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B11%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B11%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B11%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B11%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B12%5D%5Bdata%5D=weight&columns%5B12%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B12%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B12%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B12%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B12%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B13%5D%5Bdata%5D=actions&columns%5B13%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B13%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B13%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B13%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B13%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&start=0&length=10&search%5Bvalue%5D=&search%5Bregex%5D=false&_=1607960090325

**Response:**

```
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
```

As a front end dev, I'm not sure where to start debugging this.

## Update: Response from the web host:

> This issue was due to the response header being too big on the dedupe ajax > response. We had to increase proxy_buffer in nginx settings.

Comment: Is that version number correct - 5.10.4? Are you able to upgrade since in civi terms that's very old and it may no longer be an issue.

Comment: I'm running 5.22.1 and still have the error. Does anyone know if this is resolved in more recent versions?

Answer (score 1):

[dsmith63](http:///users/8784/dsmith63) has proposed an answer directly in the question. It's just a copy/paste in case it helps someone else :

He got a response from the web host:

> This issue was due to the response header being too big on the dedupe ajax response. We had to increase proxy_buffer in nginx settings.